# What's the difference between void(int) and void(*)(int)?

Tags: c++, c++11

I know void(*)(int) is a function pointer. But I'm really confused of void(int). First, they're different types

```
using A = void(int);
using B = void(*)(int);
is_same<A*, B>::value == true
```

I can initialize a variable of type B using a function pointer but not A

```
void func(int x){
    cout<<x<<endl;
}
B b { func }; //ok
A a { func }; //error
A* ap { func }; //ok
```

But if used as function parameter types, they seem to be exchangable

```
void callA(A a, int arg){ a(arg); }
void callB(B b, int arg){ b(arg); }
callA(func, 1); //ok
callB(func, 1); //ok
```

So what is void(int) indeed? When should I use void(int) and when should I use void(*)(int)?

Answer (score 3):

Your `A` is a function type, whereas your `B` is a pointer-to-function type.

You have correctly identified that these are different types, but when you use `A` as a parameter, it's silently translated into `B` (for "convenience"):

> `[C++14: 8.3.5/5]:` *[..]* After determining the type of each parameter, any parameter of type “array of `T`” or “function returning `T`” is adjusted to be “pointer to `T`” or “pointer to function returning `T`,” respectively. *[..]*

So, in that context, it arguably doesn't matter which you use.

Otherwise, you might use `A` in a template parameter expecting an actual function type, e.g. `std::function<void()>`; you would use `B` to declare a bog-standard function pointer. That's a bit like how you might use a `std::vector<int>`, or a `int*` instead.